# select_tag options should fetch data from another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-select

I am modifying Devise's registration form. I have maintain separate table for Roles. Now in my form I want to fetch all the roles as Drop down option from roles table in Registration form. I know there is need of little initialization but not aware how? I have created role column to store role in User's table. Thanks in advance :)

Here is my Code in **View file**:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :role %>
    <%= f.select_tag "role", options_for_select(@role, @selected_roles) %>
  </div>
```

**registrations_controller.rb**

```
class Devise::RegistrationsController < DeviseController
  def new
    @role = Role.all
    build_resource({})
    respond_with self.resource
  end
```

**models/role.rb**

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :access_module_roles
  has_many :access_modules, through: :access_module_roles
  scope :active, -> { where(:is_active => true) }
end
```

**Error:**

```
undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:32:in `block in  _app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_erb___501223176_87152360'
app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_erb___501223176_87152360'
app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:20:in `new'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
<%= f.select :role, Role.all.collect {|p| [ p.field_name, p.field_name ] }, { :include_blank => "Please select" } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick (as single value)

Use `@roles = Role.all` following naming conventions

stores a role name .

```
    <%= f.select(:role, @roles.map{|r| [r.attr, r.attr]}, :include_blank => "Select") %>
```

stores corresponding id.

```
  <%= f.select(:role, @roles.map{|r| [r.attr, r.id]},:include_blank=> "Select") %>
```

edit:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
```

inherit from `devise` to your `Controller`

Comment: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

Comment: set `@roles` in your `new` action

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several problems here:

First of all it is `registrations_controller.rb`

Do not forget to set inheritance from < Devise::RegistrationsController

Your controller should look like this:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
```

Change your controller file name to registrations_controller.rb

I think you forgot to 'tell' devise to use your custom controller, that's why you get undefined method map for nil:NillClass

You can do it like that:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "users/registrations" }
```

In my example above, custom **registrations_controller.rb** is nested within a module **users**, it might be different for your case, simply do not add `users` if your controller is not in the module, or add your own module if you have one.

And for the form helper it is better to use options_from_collection_for_select, because you have models here.

```
<%= f.select_tag "role", options_from_collection_for_select(@role, :id, :name, @selected_roles) %>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: check my updated ans..I have update controller portion.

Comment: Another thing I'd like to  mention is that @selected_roles should be an integer, you can not pass an array of selected values.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this Issue by correcting

in **registrations_controller.rb**

```
def new
    @roles = Role.all.collect { |m| [m.name, m.id] }
    build_resource({})
    respond_with self.resource
end
```

and in my **View**

```
<div><%= f.label :role %>
    <%= f.select(:role, @roles,:include_blank=> "Select") %>
</div>
```